# C array gets corrupted after being modified by a function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a C program that gathers all structures passing a specific condition into an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Book {
  char title[20];
  unsigned int published;
  char authors[50];
  unsigned int pages;
};

unsigned int get_books_from(unsigned int year, int length, struct Book data[], struct Book results[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct Book data[5];

  // Init book pool inside data

  struct Book books[0];
  unsigned int books_count = get_books_from(1973, 5, data, books);

  return 0;
}

unsigned int get_books_from(unsigned int year, int length, struct Book data[], struct Book results[]) {
  results = (struct Book*) malloc(sizeof(struct Book));
  unsigned int results_count = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (data[i].published == year) {
      *(results + results_count) = data[i];

      results = (struct Book*) realloc(results, (++results_count + 1) * sizeof(struct Book));
    }
  }

  return results_count;
}
```

The logic seems to be working fine, however when trying to access the `books` array contents outside of the `get_books_from` function (where it's called `results`), all the data becomes corrupted. Some of the original data is still there but not in the right places, it looks as if the data got shifted. I checked the pointers to both `books` and `results` and it appears that those variables do not point to the same place in memory after the function finishes. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is `struct Book books[0];` That doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `get_books_from` changes the value of `results` here:

```
  results = (struct Book*) realloc(results, (++results_count + 1) * sizeof(struct Book));
```

But it provides no way for the caller to get the new value of `results`.

Worse, you call `get_books_from` with `data`, which was allocated on the stack in `main`. You can't `realloc` it. As the documentation for `realloc` says, the pointer you are attempting to reallocate must been returned by a previous call to `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. Fortunately, you ignore that value. But that renders the `struct Book data[5];` in `main` incomprehensible. Why allocate space on the stack?

Comment: Oh my. You're right. I pass the pointer to function by value, it doesn't change with realloc()...

Comment: Also, you didn't dynamically allocate it, so you can't dynamically reallocate it.

Comment: I didn't? It's `malloc`ed in the first line of `get_books_from`.

Comment: Oh, so you totally ignore the value passed in!

Comment: So `struct Book data[5];` serves no purpose at all. ;)

Comment: It looks like that. I completely forgot that it gets passed by value, not by reference. Shame on me...

Comment: Personally, I would do `struct Book *data = NULL` and pass `&data` to the function. In the function, get rid of the `malloc` and just put the `realloc` before the assignment. The first `relloc`, when passed `NULL` will allocate.

Comment: Will try doing that. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer:

You probably want something like this (untested, non error checking code, declarations and #includes ommited for brevity):

```
unsigned int get_books_from(unsigned int year, int length, struct Book data[], struct Book **results);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct Book data[5];

  // Init book pool inside data

  struct Book *books;
  unsigned int books_count = get_books_from(1973, 5, data, &books);

  return 0;
}

unsigned int get_books_from(unsigned int year, int length, struct Book data[], struct Book **results) {
  *results = (struct Book*) malloc(sizeof(struct Book));
  unsigned int results_count = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (data[i].published == year) {
      *(*results + results_count) = data[i];

      *results = (struct Book*) realloc(*results, (++results_count + 1) * sizeof(struct Book));
    }
  }

  return results_count;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to dereference `results` once when passing it to `realloc`. Other than that, it works nicely. :)

Comment: @Cube. right, I've corrected. As written : this is untested code ;-). But apparently you've got the idea.